# How do I execute a function from another module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I am using python 3.6 version. I have 2 .py files as:

**modbody.py**

```
def test():
    print("Statement goes here")
```

**moduse.py**

```
import modbody
test()
```

I am trying to execute moduse.py file in python interpreter using command "Python moduse.py" however, it gives me below error:

> File "C:\users\Program\moduse.py", line 2, in 
> test() NameError: name 'test' is not defined

Please help guide me how to execute the script and call the test function here? I have also tried adding a blank **init**.py file to solve this but with no luck. Please not all of my files are in same directory only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
import modbody
modbody.test()
```

Or:

```
from modbody import test
test()
```

Or:

```
from modbody import *
test()
```